# Appcelerator: How to prevent Window.click fired when TableViewRow.click()?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have this situation where my textfield is embedded within a TableViewRow like this http://cl.ly/1i372j0Q062H010L2O0y

I wanted a situation when someone click on the "Password" row, I will focus on the Password Textfield and when someone click on anywhere else in the window, the password will get blur().

However, the problem comes in when both Window.click and PasswordRow.click got fired when the user clicks on the PasswordRow. This make the textfield.focus() and textfield.blur() got executed, resulting is no focus at all.

Anyway I can workaround it? Or is there a better way to blur it than to listen to Window.click?

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue many times before. There is a strange bug where events fired on a tableview will fire on the window. I had a problem where I had a text box set to a number pad, I had to click twice on the text box to get it to show up and then it wouldn't be a number pad.

There are many solutions on the forums such as catching the window events and doing nothing under certain circumstances, using modal windows etc. I would recommend just not using a tableView (if possible). You could probably style a view to look the same if you need it to look like that.

If you want to go the other route heres a post, one of the comments mentions filtering out other events:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117540/textfield-on-tableview-loses-focus-android